# Dealing with dependencies and keeping an app pluggable

Tags: django, django-admin, dependencies

I am working on a very basic cms/blog. for my own use it depends on django-adminfiles and django- markitup. Because I might want to distribute the app I have been  trying to figure out a way to check if those dependencies are  met and fall back to django's defaults if they are not in installed apps.

I came up with the code below and it works. Thing is it feels cumbersome and adds a lot of code to the head of the script. I was wondering if there are any other (recommended) ways of dealing with dependencies. In case I answered my own question(since the code is working) any comments are welcome.

```
from django.conf import settings as django_settings

# Check installed apps for django-markitup and django-adminfiles
if 'adminfiles' in django_settings.INSTALLED_APPS:
    from adminfiles.admin import FilePickerAdmin
    adminfiles = True

    #inherit from FilePickerAdmin
    class ModelAdmin(FilePickerAdmin):
        pass
else:
    adminfiles = False

    #inherit from admin.ModelAdmin if adminfiles =false
    class ModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
        pass

#then my own admin class inherits from ModelAdmin above    
class HomePageAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    exclude = ('slug',)    
    list_display = ('title', 'status',)
    list_filter = ('section',)

    if adminfiles:
        adminfiles_fields = ('body')
```

I can use the app in a fresh django project or remove adminfiles from installed apps and it will still work in the admin.

Comment: Do you need the if statement in your `HomePageAdmin` class? Won't the `adminfiles_fields` just be ignored if it directly subclasses `admin.ModelAdmin`?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I don't need te if statement for the adminfiles_fields, I do for the MarkitupWidget, I changed my code. I'll see if I can write a nice settings.py to turn all of this on or off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I did it eventually :

Create a settings.py file inside the app module:

```
import django
from django.conf import settings

SECTIONS_EXTRAS = getattr(settings, 'SECTIONS_EXTRAS', False)
```

I can now easily turn the setting on and off from my project's settings file.

Then added the following to admin.py:

```
from django.conf import settings as django_settings
from sections.models import HomePage,
from sections import settings

markitup = False

if settings.SECTIONS_EXTRAS:
    # Check installed apps for django-markitup and django-adminfiles
    if 'adminfiles' in django_settings.INSTALLED_APPS:
        from adminfiles.admin import FilePickerAdmin

    class ModelAdmin(FilePickerAdmin):
        pass

    if 'markitup' in django_settings.INSTALLED_APPS:
        from markitup.widgets import  MarkItUpWidget

    markitup = True
else:
    class ModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
        pass

class HomePageAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    exclude = ('slug',)

    list_display = ('title', 'status', 'section')
    list_filter = ('section',)

    # Extras

    adminfiles_fields = ('body')

    if markitup:
        def formfield_for_dbfield(self, db_field, **kwargs):
            if db_field.name == 'body':
                kwargs['widget'] = MarkItUpWidget()
            return super(HomePageAdmin, self).formfield_for_dbfield(db_field, **kwargs)
```